# malloc() and memset() behavior

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, glibc, memset

I wrote some code to see how `malloc()` and `memset()` behave, and I found a case where I don't know what's going on.

I used `malloc()` to allocate 15 bytes of memory for a character array, and I
wanted to see what would happen if I used `memset()` incorrectly to set 100 bytes of memory in the pointer I created.  I expected to see that `memset()` had set 15 bytes (and possibly trash some other memory).  What I'm seeing when I run the program is that it's setting 26 bytes of memory to the character that I coded.

Any idea why there are 26 bytes allocated for the pointer I created?  I'm compiling with gcc and glibc.  Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRLEN 14

int main(void) {

    /* + 1 for the null terminator */
    char *charptr = malloc((sizeof(*charptr) * ARRLEN) + 1);
    if (!charptr)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    memset(charptr, '\0', (sizeof(*charptr) * ARRLEN) + 1);

    /* here's the intentionally incorrect call to memset() */
    memset(charptr, 'a', 100);

    printf("sizeof(char)   ------  %ld\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("sizeof(charptr)   ---  %ld\n", sizeof(charptr));
    printf("sizeof(*charptr)  ---  %ld\n", sizeof(*charptr));
    printf("sizeof(&charptr)  ---  %ld\n", sizeof(&charptr));
    printf("strlen(charptr)   ---  %ld\n", strlen(charptr));
    printf("charptr string   ----  >>%s<<\n", charptr);

    free(charptr);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
sizeof(char)   ------  1
sizeof(charptr)   ---  8
sizeof(*charptr)  ---  1
sizeof(&charptr)  ---  8
strlen(charptr)   ---  26
charptr string   ----  >>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<<
```

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: *Any idea why there are 26 bytes allocated for the pointer I created?*  Undefined behavior is undefined.  Likely something wrote new data to the memory you corrupted with your wild `memset()`.

Comment: One of the earlier `printf()` calls probably wrote a zero to one of its own heap variables that happened to be located 11 bytes after the string you allocated.

Comment: Interestingly I see just the same, but only with optimizations disabled; turning on optimizations gives a warning about a potential buffer overflow _at compile time_ (impressive job gcc!) and crashes satisfyingly at runtime.

Comment: The `#include <unistd.h>` is unnecesssary. You don't use anything from that header.

Comment: Say you drive over the speed limit.  How fast before you are caught - if at all?  C is like that.

Comment: Aside: `(sizeof(*charptr) * ARRLEN) + 1` is conceptually wrong.  Should be `((sizeof(*charptr) + 1) * ARRLEN)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is undefined behavior, so anything can happen; as said in a comment, on my machine I get your exact same behavior with optimizations disabled, but turning on optimizations I get a warning about a potential buffer overflow *at compile time* (impressive job gcc!) and a big crash at runtime. Even better, if I print it with a `puts` before the `printf` calls I get it printed with a different number of `a`.

Still, I have the dubious luck to have the *exact* same behavior as you, so let's investigate. I compiled your program with no optimization and debug information

```
[matteo@teokubuntu ~/scratch]$ gcc -g memset_test.c
```

then I fired up the debugger and added a breakpoint on the first `printf`, just after the `memset`.

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) break 20
Breakpoint 1 at 0x87e: file memset_test.c, line 20.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/matteo/scratch/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at memset_test.c:20
20          printf("sizeof(char)   ------  %ld\n", sizeof(char));
```

now we can set a hardware write breakpoint on the 26th memory location pointed by `charptr`

```
(gdb) p charptr
$1 = 0x555555756260 'a' <repeats 100 times>
(gdb) watch charptr[26]
Hardware watchpoint 2: charptr[26]
```

... and so...

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: charptr[26]

Old value = 97 'a'
New value = 0 '\000'
_int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7dcfc40 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at malloc.c:4100
4100    malloc.c: File o directory non esistente.
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7dcfc40 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at malloc.c:4100
#1  0x00007ffff7a7b0fc in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=1024) at malloc.c:3057
#2  0x00007ffff7a6218c in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at filedoalloc.c:101
#3  0x00007ffff7a72379 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at genops.c:365
#4  0x00007ffff7a71498 in _IO_new_file_overflow (f=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at fileops.c:759
#5  0x00007ffff7a6f9ed in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=23)
    at fileops.c:1266
#6  0x00007ffff7a3f534 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, 
    format=0x5555555549c8 "sizeof(char)   ------  %ld\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffe330) at vfprintf.c:1328
#7  0x00007ffff7a48f26 in __printf (format=<optimized out>) at printf.c:33
#8  0x0000555555554894 in main () at memset_test.c:20
(gdb)
```

So, it's just `malloc` code invoked (more or less indirectly) by `printf` doing its stuff on the memory block immediately adjacent to the one it gave you (possibly marking it as used).

Long story short: you took memory that wasn't yours and it's now getting modified by its rightful owner at the first occasion when he needed it; nothing particularly strange or interesting.

Comment: The gdb walkthrough was very helpful.  I never thought to set a watchpoint for "charptr[26]", only for "charptr".

Comment: @Schmecky: glad it helped, feel free to upvote ;-) ; notice that setting a watchpoint for straight `charptr` would watch changes in value _of the pointer variable_ not of the memory it points to.

Answer (score 2):

> I used malloc() to allocate 15 bytes of memory for a character array,
>   and I wanted to see what would happen if I used memset() incorrectly
>   to set 100 bytes of memory in the pointer I created.

What happens is *undefined behavior* as far as the language standard is concerned, and whatever actually does happen in a particular case is not predictable from the source code and may not be consistent across different C implementations or even different runs of the same program.

> I expected to see
>   that memset() had set 15 bytes (and possibly trash some other memory).

That would be one plausible result, but that you had any particular expectation at all is dangerous.  Do not assume that you can predict what manifestation UB will take, not even based on past experience.  And since you should not do that, and cannot learn anything useful from that way, it is not worthwhile to experiment with UB.

> What I'm seeing when I run the program is that it's setting 26 bytes
>   of memory to the character that I coded.
>
> Any idea why there are 26 bytes allocated for the pointer I created?

Who says your experiment demonstrates that to be the case?  Not only the `memset()` but also the last `printf()` exhibits UB.  The output tells you nothing other than what the output was.  That time.

Now in general, `malloc` may reserve a larger block than you request.  Many implementations internally manage memory in chunks larger than one byte, such as 16 or 32 bytes.  But that has nothing to do one way or another with the definedness of your program's behavior, and it does not speak to your output.

Comment: So, does the last printf() exhibits undefined behavior because there's no null terminator at the end of the character array?

Comment: Yes, @Schmecky.  Or more specifically, because in the absence of a null terminator within the allocated size of the object -- as specified to `malloc()` -- `printf` will attempt an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: You're also right about experimenting with undefined behavior.  I'm basically acting like a monkey with a book of matches over here and should probably be concentrating on the standards.  Good advice.